# How do i get rails to request the gzip static asset instead of the regular one?

Tags: heroku, amazon-s3, gzip, asset-pipeline

I recently started pushing my static-assets to S3 via 'asset_sync' gem for my Heroku application.

rake assets:precompmile creates: 1) a regular version of the static asset and 2) a gzipped version of the static asset.  However, my application is loading the regular version files, instead of the gzipped version files.  How can i modify my code to fix this problem?

ps. Can i gzip fonts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I got this to work was to create zipped version of the asset with the same file name as the original, put this into S3, and set the S3 meta data content-encoding to gzip.

Sure there's a better way!